# How to update existing document in firestore using set method

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firestore document that I want to update. Here's my code -

```
admin.firestore().collection('testResult').doc(`${testId}`).set(
            {
                name: userName,
                email: email,
            },
            { merge: true },
        );
```

I am using "set" method with "merge: true" object. As I want to create a new document if it doesn't exists and update the data if it exists.

The document that I am trying to update is getting rewritten by new property that I sent, rather than appending the data in the existing document. I read that using `{merge: true}` will merge the incoming data with current data, but that's not working. My whole document is being replaced by new data.

Here's my firestore collection when I first create the document -

[image]

And here's the same document when I update it -

[image]

Comment: The code looks fine at first glance. Can you edit your question to show screenshots of the document *before* and *after* this code runs?

Comment: Absolutely. I should I have done it before.

Comment: Why aren't you using `update()` to update the data ?

Comment: Because that would fail if the collections doesn't exists. I want to create a new collection if it has not been created. And update the collection if it already exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `update()` method (or `set()` with a merge flag) creates a document that:

1. contains the value for fields that you specify.
2. any *other* fields that are already in the document.

So for any field you specify, any existing value for that field in the document *will* be overwritten.

Given that knowledge, the result is working as expected.

---

If you want to append the values you specify to the current value of that field, you'll need to [use an atomic transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) to read-and-write the document.

If you want to store multiple username+email combinations, you'll need to do so in an Array field. You can then either add the new combination with a transaction again, or (if the combination of username+email has to be unique) you can [use the atomic `array-union` operation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array)

Answer (score 3):

the `merge` doesn't create new **FIELDS**, it allows you to either ADD new fields that *don't already exist* or to selectively update specific fields.  Fieldnames are unique; in your statement:

```
admin.firestore().collection('testResult').doc(`${testId}`).set(
            {
                name: userName,
                email: email,
            },
            { merge: true },
        );
```

you are specifying the fields `name` and `email`, and EXACTLY AS THE COMMAND SAYS it is setting those fields to the new values.  If you had done:

```
admin.firestore().collection('testResult').doc(`${testId}`).set(
            {
                anotherName: userName,
                anotherEmail: email,
            },
            { merge: true },
        );
```

...it would have ADDED those fields (as in "merged new fields into the document") and left the existing fields `name` and `email` in-place

*IF* you had done:

```
admin.firestore().collection('testResult').doc(`${testId}`).set(
            {
                anotherName: userName,
                anotherEmail: email,
            },
            { merge: false },
        );
```

...(note merge: false) it would have set the DOCUMENT to

```
            {
                anotherName: userName,
                anotherEmail: email,
            },
```

...ignoring the existing fields.

Remember, fieldnames are UNIQUE in a document - you WILL NOT SEE a document like so:

```
            {
                name: userName1,
                email: email1,
                name: userName2,
                email: email2,
                name: userName3,
                email: email3,
                name: userName4,
                email: email4,
            }
```

I strongly suggest you study the documentation quite a bit more and understand exactly how Firestore documents *work*.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by doing what Frank van Puffelen suggested. Here's the correct code if anyone needs this in future -

```
admin
    .firestore()
    .collection('testResult')
    .doc(`${testId}`)
    .get()
    .then(doc => {
        if (doc.exists) {
            admin
                .firestore()
                .collection('testResult')
                .doc(`${testId}`)
                .update({
                    data: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(
                        { userName, email }
                    ),
                });
        } else {
            admin
                .firestore()
                .collection('testResult')
                .doc(`${testId}`)
                .set({
                    data: [{ userName, email }],
                });
            }
        return;
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

First I checked if the document exists. If it doesn't exists then I am creating a new document and saving a object containing an array with my values. If it exists then I am updating the array.